# How to use 'attr_accesor'

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I have a class with a private method:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :my_attr

  def some_mth?(num)
    # I want to use my_attr as a variale @myattr here
    #and here i want to check if arr include num
   @myattr.include?(num)
  end

  private

  def some_pvt_mth
    @myattr = [1,2,3,4]
    for example generation array here
  end
end
```

When I call `@myattr` inside `some_mth`, my variable  `@myattr` is `nil`

How to use variable @myatt inside class, in every method is it possible?

How do I do it properly?

Comment: Define what you mean by "proper".

Comment: _"When I call @myattr inside some_mth [...]"_ – please show the corresponding code. In your example, `some_mth` is empty and also never called. _"[...] my variable is nil"_ – that's the default value for instance variables. Why do you expect another value?

Comment: @sawa updated quiz

Comment: @Stefan updated quiz

Comment: @alfi when is `some_pvt_mth` supposed to be called?

Comment: @Stefan only once but not in `some_mth?(num)`

Comment: @alfi that's what `initialize` is for, see [Rcordova's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645050/477037)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to define `attr_accessor` in order to use an instance variable within the defined class. It's purpose is to create a 'getter' and a 'setter' method, but those are only needed for other classes to access the data.

This is a class:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @my_attr = [1,2,3,4]
  end

  def attr_includes?(x)
    @my_attr.include?(x)
  end
end
```

There's no attr accessor, but this will work.

The attr accessor essentially includes this code in your class...

```
class Foo
  def my_attr
    @my_attr
  end

  def my_attr=(x)
    @my_attr = x
  end
end
```

But if you don't want that, you can just leave it out, and access the variable via other methods (such as your include example).

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the instance variable value first:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :my_attr

  def initialize
    @myattr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  end

  def some_mth?(num)
    @myattr.include?(num)
  end
end
```

Comment: Might be obvious but instead of setting `@myattr` you could also call `some_pvt_mth` from within `initialize`

Comment: ye, but array should be generated in  `private  some_pvt_mth`

Comment: also some_pvt_mth(arg) takes some arguments

Comment: @alfi did you see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644809/how-to-use-attr-accesor#comment86300580_49645050) above? – _"[...] you could also call some_pvt_mth from within initialize"_